# MySQL - COUNT, JOIN, GROUP BY, etc

Tags: mysql

I have several tables that are all *very* similar. For example, the `bans`, `kicks`, `warnings` tables all have:

```
member, reason, staff, timestamp
```

Where `member` is their ID. A `member` may have multiple entries in each, or none.

What I'd like to do is compile the following into a single query, and then group them by member:

```sql
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS bans,     member FROM bans     GROUP BY member;
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS kicks,    member FROM kicks    GROUP BY member;
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS warnings, member FROM warnings GROUP BY member;
```

Each table can have `member`s that the other does not. For example, a member may have 2 `warnings`, but no `bans` or `kicks`. The results of the query should be:

```
member, bans, kicks, warnings
123     0     0      1
234     1     1      3
345     0     1      0
456     1     0      0
```

I am totally lost. I've tried applying and tweaking *similar* types of queries, but none of them are quite what I'm after and I can't wrap my head around them.

I know I likely have to somehow join them, but I can't figure out how and I'm just frustrating myself at this point:

```
( SELECT COUNT( * ) AS bans, member FROM bans GROUP BY member ) bans
...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a UNION query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of sub query and UNION operation to achieve it:

```
select member, max(bans) bans, max(kicks) kicks, max(warnings) warnings from
(
SELECT member, COUNT(*) AS bans, 0 as kicks, 0 as warnings FROM bans GROUP BY member
UNION
SELECT member, 0 as bans, COUNT(*) AS kicks, 0 as warnings FROM kicks GROUP BY member
UNION
SELECT member, 0 as bans, 0 as kicks, COUNT(*) AS warnings FROM warnings GROUP BY member
) as sub
group by member;
```

Note in a union operation **only** the aliases/column names of the first query in the union will be used for the outer query.

Comment: This actually works flawlessly (with a small edit that I believe @KenWhite is referring too) and very quickly. Thank you - I will try to learn from this!

Comment: @KenWhite I was just copying and pasting his sql statements I will check what is wrong and edit it. I'm just glad that OP was able to get the idea though :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the aggregation in derived tables, so you don't get a multiplier effect when you join tables with more than one entry per member. Note that if a member may occur only in one of the tables, you need a `FULL JOIN` to get this result; you can emulate that in MySQL with a `UNION` query to find all the members, joining the output of that query to the derived tables:

```sql
SELECT m.member,
       COALESCE(b.bans, 0) AS bans,
       COALESCE(k.kicks, 0) AS kicks, 
       COALESCE(w.warnings, 0) AS warnings
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT member
    FROM (
        SELECT member FROM kicks
        UNION ALL
        SELECT member FROM bans
        UNION ALL
        SELECT member FROM warnings
    ) allm
) m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS kicks, member 
    FROM kicks
    GROUP BY member
) k ON k.member = m.member
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS warnings, member 
    FROM warnings
    GROUP BY member
) w ON w.member = m.member
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS bans, member 
    FROM bans
    GROUP BY member
) b ON b.member = m.member
```

Comment: I tried this approach prior - however it only returns the member if they've had a kick. If the member has never been kicked, they don't appear.

Comment: @Stev I was just writing a note that this query requires a member to have had a kick; I assumed it was unlikely that they hadn't. I'll edit to take account of that

Comment: @Stev If you have the time/inclination, I'd be really interested in knowing how the speed of this query compares to the other answer.

Comment: My tables aren't very large (yet). Some only have 3,000 rows, but there's 7 tables. This answer runs in 0.047s according to Workbench. The accepted answer runs in 0.016s. @Nick

Comment: @Stev no worries. When they're huge come back and let me know :)

Comment: Do you think it would also be worth (performance-wise, same result) selecting DISTINCT on the tables in allm?

Comment: @Stev no, because they may contain the same values so you'd end up with duplicates because of union all. You could change union all to union but I think using union all and select distinct will perform better